# Does Hibernate detects when an id is being used?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm inserting data on a table that is also used by an java application using hibernate.

I know that Hibernate have some particulars strategies to generate the `@Ids` for entities.

My question is: would I have any problem if I choose a random id to manually insert a new data in the database. By manually I mean using a sql insert statement directly into the database.

To make myself clear, let me give an example:

(1) I have a entity `User` which the currently highest id is 10;

(2) I had to make some manual inserts directly into the database using the insert statement, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO user (id, username) values (11, 'user_11');
INSERT INTO user (id, username) values (12, 'user_12');
```

(3) Now I have to insert a new user, this time using the application. At this point, regardless of the `@GeneratedValue` strategy being set by the entity User, would hibernate check if the Id passed by the `@GeneratedValue` is available before trying to user the data?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @Leviand, PostgreSQL.

Comment: you said you have a `@GeneratedValue` annotation, are you then using the `SERIAL` generator into your table in postgres?

Comment: @Leviand, the current strategy that i'm using is @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY). I think that hibernate uses a hi/lo strategy in this case to allocate a range of Ids.

Answer (score 1):

In general `id` should be a primary key of table - this means database itself will check if it is unique and not empty. In PostgreSQL the best approach in your case will be using `serial` or `bigserial` datatype in `id` column and in Hibernate/JPA `@GeneratedValue` strategy as `sequence`. You can read more about different types of generators in [API Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id). This will move responsibility of creating new `id` to database, so behavior will be consistent between Hibernate and insert query

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you said that you are using **GenerationType.IDENTITY**

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Identity_sequencing) you can find more information, in particular:

> Although identity sequencing seems like the easiest method to assign
>   an id, they have several issues. **One is that since the id is not
>   assigned by the database until the row is inserted the id cannot be
>   obtained in the object until after commit or after a flush call.**
>   Identity sequencing also does not allow for sequence preallocation, so
>   can require a select for each object that is inserted, potentially
>   causing a major performance problem, so in general are not
>   recommended.

So teorically if you already have an insert done in your db, the table should be aware of that, but it's suggested a different solution (like using **SEQUENCE** instead)